# Using variable inside of an @include within blade

Tags: laravel

I try to use within an include, I passed in the control the variable, how do I use @foreach and look for all projects within an Include.

```
public function index(Project $project)
    {
        $project = Project::get()->all();
        return view('welcome.index',[
            'project' => $project,
        ]);
    }
```

```
@foreach ($project as $project)

          <ul class="footer-nav">

            <li class="footer-item"><a href="{{ route('project.show', $project->id )}}" class="footer-link">{{ $project->title }}</a></li>

          </ul>

@endforeach
```

Comment: `@foreach ($project as $project)` - this immediately overwrites the variable holding your original set of many projects with the first one in the set, so you lose the set.  Use a different name so you don't touch the original set, eg: `@foreach ($project as $p)`, or, more clearly: `@foreach ($projects as $project)`

Answer (score 0):

First: Project::all(); (remove get())

Them...
use $projects (plural) as $project (singular) in the foreach.

and them...
`@include('your-view', ['projects' => $projects])`